# Animated SVG Circle Background Image

Tags: svg

I need to add a background image to my SVG circle.  But, nothing I've tried thus far has worked.

Here's what I've tried so far...

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="60px" height="60px">                     
    <defs>
        <pattern id="image" x="0" y="0" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="40px" width="40px">
            <image x="0" y="0"height="40px" width="40px" xlink:href="url.png"></image>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <g transform="translate(40,40)">
        <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="20" class="circle base" fill="url(#image)"></circle>
        <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="20" class="circle progress" fill="url(#image)"></circle>
    </g>
</svg>

<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="60px" height="60px">      
    <g transform="translate(40,40)">               
        <defs>
            <pattern id="image" x="0" y="0" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="40px" width="40px">
                <image x="0" y="0" height="40px" width="40px" xlink:href="url.png"></image>
            </pattern>
        </defs>
        <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="20" class="circle base" fill="url(#image)"></circle>
        <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="20" class="circle progress" fill="url(#image)"></circle>
    </g>
</svg>

<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="60px" height="60px">           
    <filter id="this_image" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
        <feImage xlink:href="url.png"/>
    </filter>   
    <g transform="translate(40,40)">  
        <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="20" class="circle base" fill="url(#this_image)"></circle>
        <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="20" class="circle progress" fill="url(#this_image)"></circle>
    </g>
</svg>

<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="60px" height="60px">      
    <g transform="translate(40,40)">          
        <filter id="this_image" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
            <feImage xlink:href="url.png"/>
        </filter>
        <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="20" class="circle base" fill="url(#this_image)"></circle>
        <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="20" class="circle progress" fill="url(#this_image)"></circle>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/90snob59/) mockup.

Would appreciate any suggestions.  Clearly, I'm unsure whether the filter/defs-pattern should go inside the SVG or the transform

Comment: Filters are non-renderable elements (by themselves I mean), so technically it doesn't matter where you put them. By convention they should be put in a `<defs>` section. It does matter that you don't have two filters with the same `id` though - which you have in your example.

Comment: BTW, it would be helpful if you turned your block of code into a working [MCVE]

Comment: Thanks @PaulLeBeau i do not have duplicate IDs in my actual code.  Each of those 4 SVG configurations were attempted independently.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I don't believe this question is a duplicate of the one you deem this to be a duplicate of, as my SVG is animated and the one you think is a dup, is not animated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern fills are not working for one simple reason. This:

```
circle { ... fill:none; ... }
```

Comment: Thanks @PaulLeBeau!  That now shows the image repeating and not centered.  Any suggestions for centering the background image?

Comment: If you set `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"` on the image, it should be centred in the box you provide.  If you can't work it out, ask a new question.